# How can I draw cylinder on top of cylinders indicating storage figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a `Disk`/`Storage` icon as follows:

[image]

---

I was able to come up with:

```tex
\documentclass[eblocbroker.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        >=latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,shape aspect=1,
        arrow/.style={<->, >=stealth, semithick},
        block/.style={},
        every node/.style = {font=\normalsize}
        ]

        \node[
        cylinder,shape border rotate=90,draw,fill=white,
        shape aspect=0.2,font={\baselineskip=9pt},inner xsep=3pt,
        align=center,xshift=30mm,yshift=-2mm] (A) {%
            Cloud Storage \\
            \textit{...} \\
            \textit{...}
        };
        \node[
        cylinder,shape border rotate=90,draw,fill=white,yshift=-2.7mm,
        shape aspect=0.2,font={\baselineskip=9pt},inner xsep=3pt,
        align=center,xshift=30mm,yshift=-2mm] (C) {%
            Cloud Storage
        };

        \node[
        cylinder,shape border rotate=90,draw,fill=white,yshift=2.7mm,
        shape aspect=0.2,font={\baselineskip=9pt},inner xsep=3pt,
        align=center,xshift=30mm,yshift=-2mm] (B) {%
            Cloud Storage
        };


        \node[draw,circle,dashed,inner sep=-1.2pt,draw=gray!50,thick,fit=(A)] (D) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I was not able to draw sub-cyclinder in the middle. I keep the text in between to keep cyclinder's width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw the nodes from bottom to top. I suggest defining a `style` for repeated use. Include `minimum width` to keep all cylinders the same size. You can use the `positioning` library with negative `node distance` for easy placement. You can use `\phantom` text to keep the empty cylinder with the same aspect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, fit}

\tikzset{mycylinder/.style={cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.2, draw, fill=white, minimum width=2.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-4mm]
        \node[mycylinder] (C) {Cloud Storage};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of C] (A) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of A] (B) {Cloud Storage};
        \node[draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=-1.2pt, draw=gray!50, thick, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (D) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we keep same width height without `Cloud Storage` string is typed , like having white space instead?

Comment: @alper: I edited my response.

Comment: Can we apply same approch for a rectangle instead of a cyclinder?

Comment: @alper: Do you mean a rectangular solid? There is no such built-in node shape that I know of. I suggest you make a hand-drawn sketch and post it as a new question.

Comment: Yes sir the rectangle on top would be a solid. Please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687154/how-can-i-draw-solid-rectangle-on-top-of-cylinders-indicating-server-figure