# How can I draw solid-rectangle on top of rectangles indicating server figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If want to draw a `Server` icon as follows:

[image]

3-D perspective:

[image]

Original code is taken for cyclinder from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687130/127048

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, fit}

\tikzset{mycylinder/.style={rectangle, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.2, draw, fill=white, minimum width=2.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-4mm]
        \node[mycylinder, fill=orange!30] (C) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of C,yshift=5mm, fill=orange!30] (A) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of A,yshift=5mm, fill=orange!30] (B) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};

        \node [trapezium, trapezium angle=40, minimum width=25mm, draw, thick,above=of B,fill=orange!30,yshift=4mm,line width=0.2pt] (T){};

        \node[draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=-1.2pt, draw=gray!50, thick, fit=(A)(B)(C)(T)] (D) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have just replaced `cyclinder` with `rectange`.

output:

[image]

Here I was not able to give 3-D perspective and the main figure into dashed circle. Also, if possible, draw a small circle on its right corner (which is not mandatory).

Comment: For a 3D effect just draw a trapezoid on top, e.g. drawing its 4 corners and closing the path by ˋ — cycle;ˋ . Sure you can draw other objects over it. Suggestion: look up ˋ\picˋ in the manual, change one server into a pic, and stack pics instead of nodes.

Comment: I have managed drawing trapezoid but was not able to draw the other objects

Comment: Please see below. // May I make a suggestion? I'm not sure how much effort you spent on the pgfmanual, e.g. its nice tutorials in the beginning. However, it might be a good chance to look up some of the tikz-commands used in my solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciated your solution and recommendation. I was trying to learn/draw by trial and error without looking into pgfmanual. I will spend more time in pgfmanual

Comment: Great. You’ll recognize difference and progress, soon. The manual provides 3 friends to you, which I use often: TOC, find and index.

Comment: All new drawings always like a magic for me and seems impossible to draw by myself. Hopefully someday I will learn to do the magic like you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, here's a systematic way to do it.

Inspecting and trying your code showed two issues for me:

- positioning: it's not really needed, and it complicates the code
- shape trapezoid is problematic; better avoid it

So, here's my route:

- introduce a `\pic` called `serv`
- draw inside of `serv/.pic{}` whatever is needed
- place several `serv`-pics by hand
- finally place a circle by hand

To redraw one server unit I used a help grid like so, to estimate absolute coordinates; from your drawing; (0,0) is in the center of the lowest rectangle:

[image: current]

Now, this code draws:

- one server (adjust to your taste)
- first, the rectangle
- second the trapezoid as a closed path
- third, a knob with a white "frame"
- finally, one slit, placed several times

```
% new
\tikzset{
    % ~~~ a server-pic with known dimensions ~~~~~~~~~~
    serv/.pic={
        \draw[fill=orange!30] (-1.2,-.3) rectangle (1.2,.3);% rectangle
        \draw[fill=orange!30] (-1.2,.3) -- (-.7,.9) -- (.7,.9) -- (1.2,.3) -- cycle;% trapezoid
        \draw[fill=white,draw=white] (.9,0) circle [radius=1mm];% knob with a white frame
        
        \foreach \i in {0, .3, .6, .9, 1.2}% some slits
            \draw[,draw=white,line width=1.6mm] (-1+\i,-.22) -- (-.8+\i,.22);
            % one slit; stroke is quite thick
    }
}
```

The slits are simlpy thick strokes, so drawing them in white fills also its interior. If you want to have them more angled, replace my single stroke by closed path, like I did with the trapezoid, and chose a smaller line width.

[image: result]

Kindly compare my code in the beginning with your current version, while watching the `% comments`.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% better for developing drawings
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, fit}% not needed

% not needed
\tikzset{mycylinder/.style={rectangle, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.2, draw, fill=white, minimum width=2.5cm}}

% new
\tikzset{
    % ~~~ a server-pic with known dimensions ~~~~~~~~~~
    serv/.pic={
        \draw[fill=orange!30] (-1.2,-.3) rectangle (1.2,.3);% rectangle
        \draw[fill=orange!30] (-1.2,.3) -- (-.7,.9) -- (.7,.9) -- (1.2,.3) -- cycle;% trapezoid
        \draw[fill=white,draw=white] (.9,0) circle [radius=1mm];% knob with a white frame
        
        \foreach \i in {0, .3, .6, .9, 1.2}% some slits
            \draw[,draw=white,line width=1.6mm] (-1+\i,-.22) -- (-.8+\i,.22);
            % one slit; stroke is quite thick
    }
}

\begin{document}

 % ~~~ NEW ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ putting some servers into known places ~~~~~
    \pic at (0,-.7) {serv};
    \pic at (0,  0) {serv}; % center server, but not center of total image
    \pic at (0,0.7) {serv};
    
    % ~~~ drawing the circle ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [dashed,draw=gray!50, thick] (0,.2) circle [radius=18mm];% adjust y and r by iteration
 \end{tikzpicture}

% ~~~ current approach ~~~~~~~~~~
%\begin{figure}
%    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-4mm]
    \draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (3,3);
        \node[mycylinder, fill=orange!30] (C) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of C,yshift=5mm, fill=orange!30] (A) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};
        \node[mycylinder, above=of A,yshift=5mm, fill=orange!30] (B) {\phantom{Cloud Storage}};

        \node [trapezium, trapezium angle=40, minimum width=25mm, draw, thick,above=of B,fill=orange!30,yshift=4mm,line width=0.2pt] (T){};

        \node[draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=-1.2pt, draw=gray!50, thick, fit=(A)(B)(C)(T)] (D) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to label `\pic` like we do in `\node` as: `\pic at (0,-.7) {serv} (A);`? I have tried (A) next to pic but I was not able to draw a line/arrow to `(A)`

Comment: With a trick, please see my answer to your other icon question. // You could do: ˋ\node (a) at (123,456) {\tikz{ …;}};ˋ , because the node displays all valid Latex commands as text (which is tikz by chance here, which could draw a \pic).